# how to get gpu memory usage information via onnxruntime c++ api?

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, onnxruntime, inference-engine

i am now implementing a c++ inference program running on multi-gpus. I need to get every device gpu usage information to decide which gpu to run inference on. I only found the getGPUid API in onnxruntime c++ document, does it have other apis?